# ArchLinux docker CI-failed to initialise alpm library :: returned a non-zero code: 255

Tags: docker, dockerfile, archlinux

I am new to docker , I tried to create a custom image where i could simply run `pacman -Syu --noconfirm` but the following error occurred:

```
error: failed to initialize alpm library
(could not find or read directory: /var/lib/pacman/)
The command '/bin/sh -c pacman -Syu --noconfirm' returned a non-zero code: 255
```

My dockerfile is :

```
#This is a sample Image 
FROM archlinux

RUN pacman -Syu --noconfirm 
CMD [“echo”,”Image created”]
```

Comment: For me, the issue is solved by starting the container with the `--privileged` flag. `docker run -it --rm --privileged docker.io/some-archlinux-image:tag /bin/bash`. I really hate this solution, so I don't even consider it an answer.

Answer (score 10):

This workaround has worked for me. It requires patching **glibc** to an older version.

```
RUN patched_glibc=glibc-linux4-2.33-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst && \
curl -LO "https://repo.archlinuxcn.org/x86_64/$patched_glibc" && \
bsdtar -C / -xvf "$patched_glibc"
```

https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/commit/478e4de7bd1f26bebdcdc166d5369b2b5142c3e2